# HTTP 500 - HttpClient fails, browser works fine

Tags: c#, http, pdf, uwp, jetty

I'm trying to load a PdfDocument from a jetty server running on localhost, but the HttpClient returns a HTTP 500 exception every time at `client.GetStreamAsync(url)`

However, that same url works fine if I copy it to the browser (e.g. Edge).

(e.g."http://localhost:8888/data/documentation/en/pdfs.split/chunk_0001.pdf")

Am I simply overlooking something here?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(chunkURL);

var memStream = new MemoryStream();
await stream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
memStream.Position = 0;

PdfDocument loadedDoc = await PdfDocument.LoadFromStreamAsync(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
```

Comment: There should be much more info in the error than just it being a 500 response. Check that and it will tell you the problem, we can't help without knowing that problem. It could be that you're not sending the correct headers or authentication for example.

Comment: Check headers which your browser sends to server and send exactly such headers through `HttpClient`.

Comment: Perhaps the 500 error (on the server side) will tell you what happened in the logs.

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't even think of checking the headers - turns out I had totally forgotten to pass my HttpClient the cookies containing the authentification information.. Ugh.